# Replacing tick mark √ with 1

Tags: r, string, tidyverse, dplyr, recode

I have data where some students have checked by symbol √ in Excel file. I need to replace it with 1 (one) in my column(s). I have 50 values in a column where this symbol occurs. How can I do this using dplyr? or some other R function?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `str_replace` from `stringr`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)
data
  A B
1 1 √
2 2 2
3 3 √
4 4 √
5 5 2

data %>%
  mutate(B = str_replace(B,"√","1"))
  A B
1 1 1
2 2 2
3 3 1
4 4 1
5 5 2
```

You could add `as.numeric` if you want to also convert to numeric:

```
data %>%
  mutate(B = as.numeric(str_replace(B,"√","1")))
```

Sample Data

```
set.seed(3)
data <- data.frame(A= 1:5,B = gsub("1","√",round(runif(5,1,2))))
```

Comment: Thanks a lot.Yes adding as.numeric has served the purpose.